# multicolumn multirow table problem

Tags: cline

As you can see in this table, I have a problem with the length of `\cline`. Can any one help me solve this problem? Thank you very much.

[image]

I used this code

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
 \captionsetup{justification=centering}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Energy consumption \& emissions}} & \textbf{ Van }  & \textbf{Truck} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{2009}   & Energy consumption (MJ/km) & 4.6   & 13.3  \\ \cline{2-4}
                        & (CO\textsubscript{2}) (g/km)                & 340   & 973.5 \\ \cline{2-4}
                        & (NO\textsubscript{x})(g/km)                 & 1.281 & 8.048 \\ \cline{2-4}

                        & (SO\textsubscript{2}) (mg/km)               & 2.6   & 7.45  \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{2014}   & Energy consumption (MJ/km)  & 3.9   & 12.55 \\ \cline{2-4}
                        & (CO\textsubscript{2})              & 289   & 933.5 \\ \cline{2-4}
                        & (NO\textsubscript{x})(g/km)                 & 0.944 & 4.035 \\ \cline{2-4}
                        & (SO\textsubscript{2}) (mg/km)               & 1.75  & 5.55  \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{bb}\label{cc}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is caused with `@{\extracolsep{fill}}`. i suggest to replace `tabular*` with `tabularx` table environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \captionsetup{justification=centering}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|C|l|C|C| @{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Energy consumption \& emissions}}
                                    & \textbf{Van}  & \textbf{Truck}    \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{2009}
    & Energy consumption (MJ/km)    & 4.6           & 13.3              \\ \cline{2-4}
    & (CO\textsubscript{2}) (g/km)  & 340           & 973.5             \\ \cline{2-4}
    & (NO\textsubscript{x})(g/km)   & 1.281         & 8.048             \\ \cline{2-4}
    & (SO\textsubscript{2}) (mg/km) & 2.6           & 7.45              \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{2014}
    & Energy consumption (MJ/km)    & 3.9           & 12.55             \\ \cline{2-4}
    & (CO\textsubscript{2})         & 289           & 933.5             \\ \cline{2-4}
    & (NO\textsubscript{x})(g/km)   & 0.944         & 4.035             \\ \cline{2-4}
    & (SO\textsubscript{2}) (mg/km) & 1.75          & 5.55              \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{bb}\label{cc}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

however i would  design table without vertical lines and  `\cline`, and `\hline` replace with rules from `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X l *{2}{S[table-format=5.3]} }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Energy consumption \& emissions}}
                                    & \mcx{Van}  & \mcx{Truck}    \\ 
    \midrule
2009
    & Energy consumption (MJ/km)    & 4.6           & 13.3              \\ 
    & (CO\textsubscript{2}) (g/km)  & 340           & 973.5             \\
    & (NO\textsubscript{x})(g/km)   & 1.281         & 8.048             \\
    & (SO\textsubscript{2}) (mg/km) & 2.6           & 7.45              \\ 
    \midrule
2014
    & Energy consumption (MJ/km)    & 3.9           & 12.55             \\ & (CO\textsubscript{2})         & 289           & 933.5             \\ & (NO\textsubscript{x})(g/km)   & 0.944         & 4.035             \\ & (SO\textsubscript{2}) (mg/km) & 1.75          & 5.55              \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{bb}\label{cc}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
with use of `mhchem` package and shading particular cells in table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X l *{2}{S[table-format=5.3]} }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Energy consumption \& emissions}}
                                    & \mcx{Van} & \mcx{Truck}       \\ 
    \midrule
2009
    & Energy consumption (MJ/km)    & 4.6       & 13.3              \\ 
    & \cellcolor{gray!20}{\ce{CO2}} 
                    (g/km)          & 340       & 973.5             \\
    & \ce{NO_{x}}   (g/km)          & 1.281     & 8.048             \\
    & \ce{SO2}      (mg/km)         & 2.6       & 7.45              \\ 
    \midrule
2014
    & Energy consumption (MJ/km)    & 3.9       & 12.55             \\ 
    & \cellcolor{gray!20}{\ce{CO2}} & 289       & 933.5             \\
    & \ce{NO_{x}}   (g/km)          & 0.944     & 4.035             \\ 
    & \ce{SO2}      (mg/km)         & 1.75      & 5.55              \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{bb}\label{cc}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @helloWorld998, now i complete my answer. see second part ...

Comment: what do you mean by second part Zarko, i'm sorry could you please explain

Comment: suggestion for table which is second in my answer

Comment: oh i see, this also great, but why the values 340 and 289 are justified

Comment: if i want to colour only the box around CO2 how can i do it?

Comment: numbers are justified at decimal point. coloring ... you need add package `[table]{xcolor}` and then write `\cellcolor{gray!10}{CO\textsubscript{2}}`. btw, for writing chemical formulas the some `mhchem` package can be handy.

Comment: Very good you are my savior Zarko :) thanks.

Comment: @helloWorld998, now i add example where i for chem formulas i use `mhchem` package and show how to show one cell.